# add multiple static ip addresses to a server with systemd-networkd

Tags: networking, ip, ipv4, systemd

We have a server with multiple IP adresses. Lately we migrated to systemd and we still need mutliple IPs on that server. With systemd-networkd we have some trouble finding a configuration example. so we use a bash script at the end of the boot process to add the ips to the interface.

Can someone provide a systemd-networkd config example for adding more than one IP to one interface.

Comment: Have you checked `man systemd.network` ? Just a sidenote, you don't have to go ALL in an use systemd-networkd. What distribution are we talking about?

Comment: We checked the manpage. I think it is very compatible and portable if we use systemd-netword, as it will be available on all distros soon. Distro is gentoo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [systemd.network(5)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html), you can simply add multiple `Address=` lines to the `[Network]` section, with the required addresses.

```
[Network]
Address=10.2.3.4/16
Address=10.6.7.8/16
Gateway=...
```

Alternatively, create a separate `[Address]` section for each address.

```
[Network]
Gateway=...

[Address]
Address=10.2.3.4/16

[Address]
Address=10.6.7.8/16
```

(The same applies to `[Route]` sections and `Gateway=` parameters.)

Note that *systemd-networkd* is still very new and receives bug fixes almost daily. Make sure you're using the latest systemd release, and test the Git builds if possible. See the [mailing list](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html) and the IRC channels `#systemd` & `#gentoo-systemd` on freenode in case of bugs.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the first method does not seem to work (only the first IP address is reachable). However, the second method, with separate `[Address`] sections, does work. For what it's worth, I have defined a single gateway under the `[Network]` section, as in the second example. I should add also that I am unable to get two static IP addresses working on two separate physical network interfaces, no matter what I try (I have yet to find an example of this in the `systemd` documentation or elsewhere on the web), so I'm left to settle for two IP addresses on a single interface.

Comment: doesn't work in Arch Linux, SystemD 249.2-1

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a container under Proxmox, and Proxmox writes its own `/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network` in the container.  To get around not being able to rely on that file not being overwritten, you can create a drop-in file with the additional IP address(es), `/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network.d/additional-ips.conf`

```
[Match]
Name = eth0

[Address]
Address = 192.168.1.102/24
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Arch Linux, SystemD 249.2-1, none of these (3) methods work ([tried this answer too](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297426/how-do-i-to-set-multiple-ip-addresses-on-an-interface-in-systemd))

```
-------------------------
[Network]
Address=10.2.3.4/16
Address=10.6.7.8/16
-------------------------
[Network]
Address=192.168.59.1/24 192.168.1.5/24
-------------------------
[Address]
Address=10.2.3.4/16

[Address]
Address=10.6.7.8/16
-------------------------
```

Instead, using a simple SystemD service, you can set a second IP after boot... See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd) for more details on systemd service creation... Bonus point: this method allows you to have static or DHCP for the primary address.

- touch /usr/local/bin/second_ip
- chmod +x /usr/local/bin/second_ip
- edit file as per below

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> ip address add 10.10.128.128/16 dev eth0
> ```

- touch /etc/systemd/system/second-ip.service
- edit file as per below
- systemctl enable second-ip

  ```
   [Unit]
   Description=second ip service
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   User=root
   ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/second_ip                                                                                      Type=simple

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```